# Are Three internal style sheets and no script tag right way for my webpage?

Tags: php, wordpress, css

I am having a three **internal** style sheets and one **external** style sheet in my web page. Simplified output looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<title>Some title</title> 

<!--This is a NORMAL external stlesheet-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="http://localhost/wp-content/themes/My_Theme/css/style.css" />

<!--Will display SINGLE COLUMN instead TWO COLUMNS if no JS enabled-->  
<noscript>
<style type="text/css">
.col1{

width:100%;
margin:0px;
display:block;
position:relative;      
}
</style>
</noscript> 

<!--This is MY DYNAMIC stylesheet generated by SOME PHP-->
<style type="text/css">

#blogwrapper{   
width: 530px;
margin-left:6px;    
}
</style>

<!--This is also DYNAMIC stylesheet BUT generated WORDPRESS PHP-->
<style type="text/css" id="custom-background-css">
body.custom-background { background-color: #1e73be; }
</style>
</head>
</body>
</html>
```

My page passes HTML and CSS Validation ,but I am still having doubts is it a right way for implementing my CSS this way.
 So my question is: am I doing this right or not (because I am developing a Wordpress theme and I want to make it publicly available , so don't want my theme **being rejected** by Wordpress Review Team ) ?

Comment: why you want to write internal style three times even it is valid?

Comment: Third Inline style is generated my Wordpress itself,external CSS is static CSS , so for example if user is activated a sidebar I want to adjust my page content (shrink it a bit to accommodate space generated by sidebar) only way for doing that is by PHP or JS...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

writing inline style sheets on the HTML/PHP page is always unwelcome even if it works.
It has following disadvantages:

1. The page code gets lengthy
2. The style sheet becomes available only for the specific page.
3. Its tedious to change the style sheet for designer in future
   purpose.

Therefore, even if it works, please remove the inline style sheets and move them to separate CSS files.
Same for JavaScript file.

Thanks.

Comment: Well I am NOT writing my inline styles directly they are Imported by my PHP (separate file's)...

Comment: Downvoter, I request you the reason for downvote. I will take care from the next time.